# problem with longtable in landscape orientation in a twocolumn mode document

Tags: tables, margins, longtable, two-column, landscape

I have some trouble formatting a long table in landscape orientation using a predefined document class (provided by a journal editor):
- the standard page size is shrunk: the height of the page (width of the table) is reduced with respect to a standard page,
- the table is out of the page: laying over the header of the page
N.B.: the article is in a twocolumn mode

The warning indicates:

```
(no line number in this file):
Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition
 of \endfigure, most likely
 \let\endfigure=\end@float
 which has now been changed to
 \def\endfigure{\end@float}
 because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float
 (like done by several packages changing float behaviour)
 can't take effect on \endfigure.
 Please complain to your document class author.
```

The only way I could reformat more or less in a descent way is editing the page specifications:
`\setlength\LTleft{-180pt} and \footskip = 200pt`

Please let me know if you have any other suggestion.

The document is available on writelatex.com and can be edited or downloaded at the following URL:
https://www.writelatex.com/351847jnrdzr
N.B.: you can save your modifications using the history tab
Thanks.

the table looks like:

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}

    \begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{8in} % default: 4in (rather less than \textwidth...)
\setlength\LTleft{-180pt}            % default: \parindent
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
\footskip = 200pt
\onecolumn
\tablehead{Table table table table table table table table table Table.}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{10}{llcccccccc}}
\label{table:table} \\
\hline
\\
 &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{multicolumn1} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{multicolumn2} \\
 \\
 \cline{3-5} \cline{7-10} \\
column1 & column2 & column3$^a$ & column4 & column5$^b$ & & column7 & column8 & column9 & column10 \\
\\
\hline
\\
Type & Name$^c$ & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & NNNNN && PPPPPP$^b$(-)& X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & N-X,XXX,XXX$^c$ \\

Type & Name$^c$ & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & NNNNN && PPPPPP$^b$(-)& X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & N-X,XXX,XXX$^c$ \\

Type & Name$^c$ & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & NNNNN && PPPPPP$^b$(-)& X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & X,XXX,XXX-X,XXX,XXX(?) & N-X,XXX,XXX$^c$ \\

\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
$^a$ Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text.
$^b$ Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\twocolumn

\end{landscape}
```

bioinfo.cls:

```
\newcommand\classname{bioinfo}
\newcommand\lastmodifieddate{2003/02/08}
\newcommand\versionnumber{0.1}

% Are we printing crop marks?
\newif\if@cropmarkson \@cropmarksontrue

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2001/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[\lastmodifieddate\space\versionnumber]

\setlength{\paperheight}{11truein}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5truein}

\newif\if@final

\DeclareOption{draft}{\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{\PassOptionsToPackage{a4}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{centre}{\PassOptionsToPackage{center}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{crop}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cam}{crop}\global\@cropmarksontrue}
\DeclareOption{nocrop}{\PassOptionsToPackage{off}{crop}\global\@cropmarksonfalse}
\DeclareOption{info}{\PassOptionsToPackage{info}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{noinfo}{\PassOptionsToPackage{noinfo}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\global\@finaltrue}

\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,nocrop,centre,info}

\ProcessOptions

% Load all necessary packages
\RequirePackage{inputenc,crop,graphicx,amsmath,array,color,amssymb,flushend,stfloats,amsthm,chngpage,times}
%\RequirePackage[LY1]{fontenc}
%\RequirePackage[LY1,mtbold]{mathtime}
\def\helvetica{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\def\helveticaitalic{\fontfamily{phv}\itshape\selectfont}
\def\helveticabold{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries\selectfont}
\def\helveticabolditalic{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries\itshape\selectfont}
```

...

Comment: Please make a small example document _on this site_  having a link to an editable file doesn't really fit the format of this site. You mention longtable in two-column but longtable does not support two column by default, also your error message is about a figure and you can not use longtable in figures as they are an unbreakable box.

Answer (score 2):

The example posted in your question can not be run, please always include `\documentclass` and all needed packages.

However as far as I can see the problem is simply that your table is too wide.

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{10}{llcccccccc}}
```

`tabular` `l` and `c` columns never allow line breaking so each cell is a single line (and you have specified 100 such columns which seems excessive, although not strictly an error as extra columns are ignored.) I suspect you intended

```
\begin{longtable}{llcccccccc}
```

But in any case you probably want something like

```
\begin{longtable}{llp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
```

or whatever width column manes sense for your real data.

The question appears to have nothing at all to do with the error about figures that you posted, if that is in the same document it is a different issue entirely.

Comment: I've added the missing information on the document class